# What means 狂擺 in Cantonese?

Tags: cantonese

I don't understand these two characters in Miss Hong Kong 2020 contestant [Rosanna Tse's IG post](https://www.instagram.com/p/CE6qlAvFtCf/). At 18 she's youngest.  She's thanking Miss Friendship, Maisie Kwong, who's 24.

Here's my translation of line 4. I presume [颠咗 means 傻了 in Cantonese](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/139162239.html).

Remember this silly girl was in front you posing sillyly 狂擺.

> 上次影咗唔記得po添
> ...諗嘢諗嘢諗嘢諗嘢...
> 多謝Maisie揸機
> [4.] 望住個傻妹係你面前顛咗咁**狂擺**pose
> 你影相好靚❣
> 記得呢日係第一次通宵，我地都仲係精神寶寶
> 多謝你成日陪我傾計❤❤❤
> 要繼續咁靚女喔

Answer (score 1):

The Mandarin counterpart of 颠咗 is 瘋了

颠咗咁 = 瘋了地 (like crazy)

狂 (adv): madly; like crazy (repeatedly; rapidly; in an indulgent manner)

擺 (v): strike / make

姿勢 (n):  pose

> 颠咗咁狂擺 pose = rapidly striking poses like crazy

> 望住個傻妹係你面前颠咗咁狂擺 pose = watching the dumb girl rapidly striking poses like crazy

Other examples of 狂 as an adverb

喺日本**狂**食海鮮 - eat seafood **like crazy** (in an indulgent manner) in Japan

**狂**數對方十蛋 - score on the other team **like crazy** (repeatedly) for ten goals